# Return type is array but string returned

Tags: php, php-7.1

IS there anything wrong in this declaration please help, am getting error:-

My code

```
public function function(): array
{
    return $this->data['value'] ?? [];
}
```

Error am getting is:- Function should return an array but string returned.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple example, your function declaration is wrong :

```
<?php
    function test() {
       return $this->data['value'] ?? [];
    }

    $result = test();
?>
```

Comment: The function declaration looks fine to me, are you seeing something I'm missing?

Comment: first don't call your function : "function", and the : array to return an array is wrong

Comment: I agree that `function` is probably not the best of names, but it does seem to [work](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c131da9b49170cab95867a2a98c4322e5f6eae98). Also, `array` is a [valid return type](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)

Comment: In php you don't have to define return type..

Comment: and function is NOT a valid name... you will get an error